# Filter com 2 Array de Objetos

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer um filter utilizando 2 array de objetos para que o primeiro nao tenha as mesmas informações que o segundo ex:

```
valorA = [{nome: 'rafael', valor: 29}, {nome: 'diego', value: 21},{nome: 'tiago', value: 12}]

valorB = [{nome: 'rafael', valor: 29}, {nome: 'diego', value: 21}]


// valorA tem que vir somente com tiago, 
valorA = valorA.filter(valor => {
     return valor.nome != valorB[index].nome
})
```

Estou tentando algo mais ou menos assim mais nao sai, alguem pra me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isto você precisa verificar para cada elemento de `A` se o mesmo existe dentro `B`, você pode fazer de diversas formas, uma simples seria usando o [Find Index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), basicamente para cada valor em `A` você procura pelo correspondente index do mesmo em `B`, se não existe agora a condição do `filter` será satisfeita e o novo array terá os valores diferentes de A e B.

```js
const valorA = [{nome: 'rafael', valor: 29}, {nome: 'diego', value: 21},{nome: 'tiago', value: 12}]
const valorB = [{nome: 'rafael', valor: 29}, {nome: 'diego', value: 21}]


const valorC = valorA.filter(valor => valorB.findIndex(vB => vB.nome === valor.nome) === -1);

console.log(valorC)
```